# How to retrieve the objects participating in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a many-to-many relationship between User(Contributor) and TaskType. I want to assign to a variable only TaskTypes that have the current user among their contributors. Obviously, I can somehow do this using the functionality of the Entity Framework. But how? I use asp.net core 3.

Below I try unsuccessfully to do it:

```
    public IQueryable<TaskType> ContributedTaskTypes
    {
        get
        {
            // This code doesn't work!
            return _dbContext.TaskTypes.Where(t => t.Contributors.Contains(c => c.UserId == CurrentUserId));
        }
    }
```

Below are definitions of all models involved in this relationship:

```
public class TaskType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contribution> Contributors { get; set; }
}

public class Contribution
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    public TaskType TaskType { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Contribution> ContributedToTaskTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where `Contains` method is coming from? It should be `Any` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those queries it is always easiest to do queries where you can dot to the result.

Here is the query with sql-like syntax

```
from row in _dbContext.Contribution
where row.UserId == CurrentUserId
select row.TaskType
```

By selecting row.TaskType instead of just row you get it correct entity.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is that `Contributors` property **retrieved correctly** from DB? if it is not you must call `Include()` method to load/refer relational referenced entities

   `_dbContext.TaskTypes.Include(p=>p.Contributors).Where(..`

more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

2. In Addition, if EF Core Table Relation is not correctly defined, you should follow
   this instruction: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx